# AVHRR Max NDVI product

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, ndvi

I'm trying to take a max annual NDVI product derived from AVHRR and relate it to a specific area that I'm examining.This requires me to identify the region of interest based on Landsat scenes, and relate it to AVHRR's raster resolution. I know what area I want to look at in the Landsat scenes, but am having trouble translating it to area in AVHRR, which is currently projected in North Pole Lambert Azimuth Equal Area.

[image]

My landsat layer is currently projected in UTM Zone 13N.

[image]

I have tried switching both projections to something compatible, with each to USA Contigous Lambert Conformal Conic, but there still seems to be a fundamental projection issue occurring. The region of interest is in NM, and it doesn't appear the AVHRR scene is lining up as shown:

[image]

The basemap is projecting in WGS84, and it appears as though the reprojected landsat scene conforms with the baseman, whereas the AVHRR scene does not.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more details about the oprojections of the AVHRR and Landsat images?

Comment: I just added images. Maybe that will help clarify my problem. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a lingering projection issue. The NDVI scenes were default projecting in Arc as a similar, but different projection (sorry, I can't remember what it was off the top of my head), whereas the assigned projection from USGS was Lambert Azimuth Equal Area. The projection along with a tutorial of how to correct the issues are posted at the following link:

http://phenology.cr.usgs.gov/get_data_tutorial.php

The page has a LAEA projection to download and specific instructions to reproject it in Arc with the LAEA projection available on the page. I downloaded it and followed the tutorial and everything worked great!

Here's a screen grab of what everything looked like after I followed the tutorial:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just find the projection type of one of your satellite image and project your other satellite image and the digitized layer to the same projection type.